# Add another style without removing the previous (CKEditor 4)

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I've been looking through a lot of documentation and examples, but I haven't found an answer. Here's my problem, I have the following code inside my CKEditor stylesSet:

```
{name: 'Full Column Photo', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'full-
column' }, childRule: function( element ) {
    return !element.is( 'img' );
}},
{ name: 'Disable Image Popup', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 
'disable-popup' }, childRule: function( element ) {
return !element.is( 'img' );
} },
```

If I have an element that has the style/class ".full-column" and then add the style/class ".disable-popup" to that same element, '.full-column' gets removed. How can I keep both classes in the element? And how can I remove only the selected style/class if it's already been selected for the element before.

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you can add a class to an elements existing class list using the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property. The property exposes the `add` function which can be used to add a new class name to the list.

You first need to get a reference to the DOM element you wish to manipulate.

```
const el = document.getElementById('some-element');
```

Next you can add the class you want to the element

```
el.classList.add('new-class');
```

Alternatively if you want to later remove the class you can use the `remove` function.

```
el.classList.remove('new-class');
```

---

Edit: In light of your comment, would you be able to specify the `attributes.class` property as a function that returns  the object you have. Something like:

```
{ 
    name: 'Disable Image Popup', 
    element: 'img', 
    attributes: { 
          'class': function() {
            element.addClass('disable-popup');
            return '';
        }
    }, 
    childRule: function( element ) {
        return !element.is( 'img' );
    }
}
```

Weirdly, I don't think there is a function that will return the `CKEDITOR.dom.element` classes on the element, only the styles or a `hasClass()` function.

Comment: Thanks Luke! Just wondering what would be the way to get this functioning inside CKEditor, as the adding/removing of a class works as is with stylesSet, but I would somehow need to add this classList property, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Luke, unfortunately that throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: @nikoka my mistake, I was missing parentheses on the function. `'class': function()` updated.

Comment: Thanks so much for not giving up Luke, this now throws "Uncaught TypeError: d.class.split is not a function
    at CKEDITOR.filter.allow (ckeditor.js:226)
    at CKEDITOR.filter.allow (ckeditor.js:226)
    at CKEDITOR.filter.addFeature (ckeditor.js:230)
    at addFeature (ckeditor.js:279)"